# Multi-thread using Enqueue, Dequeue. Dequeues same data even there is no duplicate data

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

There are 2 threads, `Enqueue Thread` and `Dequeue Thread`. Enqueue Thread receives data from `UDP Socket(multicast)` and Dequeue Thread dequeue data and parsing sentence.

I was trying to findout why dequeue Thread gets duplicated data even there are no duplicated data in ConcurrentQueue.

What will be the possible problem?

Enqueue Thread Code

```
private void Server_MulticastReceiveThread()
{
   Socket mcastSocket;
   ReceiveDataType InsertQueue; // To insert Queue
   byte[] data = new byte[1024]; // Receive Data
   InsertQueue.data = data;
   int recv;
   
    
   while (true)
   {
      try
      {
         recv = mcastSocket.ReceiveFrom(~ ,ref remoteEndPoint); 

         Server_Queue.Enqueue(InsertQueue);

      }
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
         Thread.Sleep(INTERVAL_30); 
         continue; 
      }

      string path = @"C:\Users\SAN\Downloads\Enqueue.txt";
      string Test = Encoding.Default.GetString(InsertQueue.data);
      using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
      {
         sw.WriteLine(Test);
      }
   }
}
```

Dequeue Thread Code. ExtractQueue.data is just byte array.

```
   private void Server_MulticastDequeueThread()
   {
      string rxSentence = "";  // received entire Sentence
      string tagblockSentence = ""; // For Tagblock ONLY
      string nmeaSentence = ""; // For NMEA-Sentence ONLY
      int queuecount = 0;
      string _dataReceiveTime;
      while (true)
      {
              
         while (Server_Queue.TryDequeue(out ExtractQueue))
         {
            try
            {
               if (ExtractQueue.data == null)
                  continue;

               rxSentence = Encoding.Default.GetString(ExtractQueue.data); 

               string path = @"C:\Users\SAN\Downloads\Dequeue.txt";
               string Test = rxSentence;
               using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
               {
                  sw.WriteLine(Test);
               }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               Log.SaveLog(LogLevel.ZERO, " " + e.Message);
            }

         }

         Thread.Sleep(1);
                
      }

   }
```

Enqueue.txt Result.

```
UdPbC \s:SI0005,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.542*19\$ERUID,12,148*71
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0004,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.553*18\$ERUID,11,147*7D
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0005,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.572*1a\$ERUID,12,148*71
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0004,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.596*11\$ERUID,11,147*7D
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0005,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.605*19\$ERUID,12,148*71
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0004,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.627*18\$ERUID,11,147*7D
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0005,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.638*17\$ERUID,12,148*71
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0003,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.649*17\$ERUID,7,141*4C

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0003,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.649*17\$ERUID,8,142*40

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0003,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.649*17\$ERUID,9,143*40

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0003,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.649*17\$ERUID,10,144*7F
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0004,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.649*10\$ERUID,11,147*7D
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0005,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.660*1a\$ERUID,12,148*71
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0004,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.670*1a\$ERUID,11,147*7D
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC0\s:IC0001,d:SI0011*2a\$ICHBT,,A,*39
10.670*1a\$ERUID,11,147*7D
```

Dequeue.txt Result

```
UdPbC \s:SI0005,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.572*1a\$ERUID,12,148*71
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0005,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.572*1a\$ERUID,12,148*71
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0004,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.627*18\$ERUID,11,147*7D
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0004,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.670*1a\$ERUID,11,147*7D
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0004,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.670*1a\$ERUID,11,147*7D
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0004,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.670*1a\$ERUID,11,147*7D
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC0\s:IC0001,d:SI0011*2a\$ICHBT,,A,*39
10.670*1a\$ERUID,11,147*7D
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0005,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.691*14\$ERUID,12,148*71
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0004,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.692*16\$ERUID,11,147*7D
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0004,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.745*1d\$ERUID,11,147*7D
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
UdPbC \s:SI0004,d:IC0001,n:123,t:220710060010.777*1c\$ERUID,11,147*7D
```

Comment: I assume that the `Server_Queue` is a `readonly` field of type `ConcurrentQueue<ReceiveDataType>`, correct? What kind of type is the `ReceiveDataType`? Is it `class` or `struct`? Is it mutable or immutable?

Comment: As a side note, instead of pulling a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` with `while (true)`-`TryDequeue`-`Thread.Sleep(1)`, it should be more efficient and more responsive to use a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) instead.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias ```Server_ Queue``` is ```readonly``` type and ReceiveDataType is struct and it only has ReceiveDaraType.data. It is byte array and mutable.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I will try ```BlockingCollection<T>``` Thank you.

Comment: Since the `ReceiveDataType` is mutable, you should be extra careful not to mutate it after inserting it in the collection. Otherwise the duplicate data might be caused by concurrent mutations. You could consider replacing the mutable array with an `ImmutableArray<T>`, so that you don't even have to think about the implications of mutations in a multithreaded environment.